# input text box get NaN value

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, nan, typeof

I want write a sum of values in a textbox. For that I have this two parts of code:

HTML:

```
<label for="test1">Value(€)</label>
<input type="text" name="test1" id="test1" value="0"><br>
```

Javascript:

```
function selected_feature(event){
    //set to 0
    document.getElementById('test1').value = 0;

    //Loop
    for(var i=0; i<elements.selectedFeatures.length; i++)   {
        var elements;
        elements += parseFloat(elements.selectedFeatures[i].attributes.value_elements);
        document.getElementById('test1').value = elements;
    }

}
```

http://pastebin.com/N2jnaQ4x

Conclusion: I get the value 'NaN' in textbox. I have tried many things with 'parsefloat' but nothing works. If i make an 'alert (typeof elements')' in the end of function i get 'number'.
Why textbox received 'NaN'?Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what 'selectedFeatures' contains. At first sight I would say that at least one of them doesn't contain a number (so 'parseFloat' returns NaN).

Comment: If not a number why i get a number in result of type off?

Comment: I use typeof to see the variable type and i get always 'number':  http://pastebin.com/7EUWA4Kv

Comment: because 'elements' IS a number (NaN is a number!) but (one or more) of the items of 'elements.selectedFeatures[i].attributes.value_elements' is not a number (then 'parseFloat' returns NaN and 'elements' will be NaN forever).

Comment: I think there is issue in accessing childnodes, so you are getting NaN(not a number)
you check whether... **parseFloat(elements.selectedFeatures[i].attributes.value_elements)** is returning a number..
...however apart from that your assignment (**document.getElementById('test1').value = elements;**) should be after the for loop..

Answer (score 1):

based on debugging, i think the problem is that the input textbox declaration for the value field is not declared with an integer value. I found this out in this jsFiddle perhaps try setting the value to 0 or blank in the value field of the two input text boxes in the code. instead of the textbox. you'll see that when you click the "Add the two values" it will shows us NaN.. but when the input text field has the integer value when ran.. You will see that it will add up.. I still havent figured out how to fix this - anyway, just sharing..

Try this

```
 <input type="text" id="one" value="" />
 <input type="text" id="two" value="" />
```

VS this

Try this

```
 <input type="text" id="one" value="20" />
 <input type="text" id="two" value="30" />
```

in the below

[JSFiddle Code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/adeshpandey/Y3xmW/)

Signing Out - Lakhi Calantoc of Nouvre Technologies